list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple - Python -Poker
I would like some help. The goal os this function is to find if there is a pair in a set of cards and find out which are them.
I am able to reach the value with the print command, but my for loop is broken.
def check_pair(cards):
    print(cards)  #works
    print(cards[1][1]) #works
    for i in cards:
        ranks.append(cards[i][0])
    pairs = {k:ranks.count(k) for k in ranks}
    return pairs

community_cards = [(1, 'd'), (2, 'h'), (1, 'h')]

print(f'Checking pair: {check_pair(community_cards)}')

File "e:\Python_Books\Python Crash Course\poker.py", line 42, in check_pair
ranks.append(cards[i][0])
~~~~~^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
PS E:\Python_Books\Python Crash Course>

Not reproducible, ranks is not defined. Please, fix it

Does this answer your question? TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple even when indices appears to be an integer

Your code is crashing because you didn't declare the ranks variable. To run your code declare ranks as a list.
By the way your code can be more improved on the basis of time complexity as count(k) time complexity is O(n) and its for every element in ranks it is finally a O(n^2).
def check_pair(cards):
    pairs = {}

    for card in cards:
        if card[0] not in pairs:
            pairs[card[0]] = 1
        else:
            pairs[card[0]] += 1

    return pairs


community_cards = [(1, 'd'), (2, 'h'), (1, 'h')]

print(f'Checking pair: {check_pair(community_cards)}')

This code doesn't need extra space also.

When you iterate over list, you iterate over objects, not indexes.
So when you have
x = ['el_1', 'el_2', 'el_3']

and you try to iterate
for i in x:
    print(i)

you will see
el_1
el_2
el_2

So in your case when you iterate over cards
for i in cards:

i is already a card, not index. You just need to use
ranks.append(i[0])



ranks does not exist. Use ranks as a list().
Append card[0] instead of cards[i][0] to ranks:

def check_pair(cards):
    ranks = []
    for card in cards:
        ranks.append(card[0])
    pairs = {k: ranks.count(k) for k in ranks}
    return pairs

community_cards = [(1, 'd'), (2, 'h'), (1, 'h')]

print(f'Checking pair: {check_pair(community_cards)}')



If you have the ranks, then pass it to the function:

def check_pair(cards, ranks):
    ...

